# Visual Studio 2010 SDK installation can't find Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-sdk

Anyone have experience with the Visual Studio SDK and can help point me in the right direction to solving this <strike>problem</strike> odd behavior?

[image]

To summarize the screenshot, I have Visual Studio 2010 installed (no it's not a new installation) but the SDK installer seems to think I don't.

Yes I've tried more than once and yes I closed Visual Studio before trying to install the SDK.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Someone found a solution to a problem that looks like yours:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/windowssdk/thread/ac4fab28-ab07-4b3c-b46c-8b6b293068c8

Comment: Thread lead me to the problem being there is a specific [SDK SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=21835) that must be installed if you have VS SP1.

Comment: @Terry Wow I thought it was a joke, same filename and same size... But it worked!